# Eclipse CDT Cygwin error

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, cygwin

i have a problem with eclipse CDT and cygwin, when i try to build a simple hello world project i have this error:

```
 make all 
Building file: ../src/test.cpp
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/test.d" -MT"src/test.d" -o "src/test.o" "../src/test.cpp"
C:\shell.w32-ix86\make.exe: *** [src/test.o] Error 1

14:37:48 Build Finished (took 178ms)
```

Cygwin is in the path and commands like 'g++' or 'make' works fine.

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: What happens if you run `make all` from a Cygwin prompt?
What happens if you run `make all` from a cmd.exe window?

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html) tutorial to properly set up cygwin with Eclipse CDI. After completing all the steps, add one more path dependency on: `Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes GNU C++` with the value to : `${CYGWIN_HOME}/usr/i686-pc-cygwin/sys-root/usr/bin`. This solved all the issues arising on Eclipse CDT with CYGWIN.